# The module has a bad import

Tags: date, elm

While trying to import the Date module and using it in a simple Elm file, I'm getting the following error:

```
-- UNKNOWN IMPORT ---------------------------- app/javascript/CountdownTimer.elm

The CountdownTimer module has a bad import:

    import Date

I cannot find that module! Is there a typo in the module name?

The "source-directories" field of your elm.json tells me to only look in the src
directory, but it is not there. Maybe it is in a package that is not installed
yet?
```

CountdownTimer is the name of the file and the module, taken from [here](https://github.com/pragmaticstudio/tutorial-elm-with-rails/blob/master/app/javascript/CountdownTimer.elm), which seems to work fine, but not for me.

I'm using Elm 0.19.0 and Rails 6.0.0beta1, which seems not to be a constraint, since if I enter to the Elm REPL in any place, and try to import date, I face the same error:

```
> import Date
-- UNKNOWN IMPORT ---------------------------------------------------------- elm

The Elm_Repl module has a bad import:

    import Date

I cannot find that module! Is there a typo in the module name?

When creating a package, all modules must live in the src/ directory.
```

My elm.json file looks like:

```
{
    "type": "application",
    "source-directories": [
        "src"
    ],
    "elm-version": "0.19.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "direct": {
            "elm/browser": "1.0.1",
            "elm/core": "1.0.2",
            "elm/html": "1.0.0",
            "elm/time": "1.0.0",
            "elm/json": "1.1.2",
            "elm/url": "1.0.0",
            "elm/virtual-dom": "1.0.2"
        },
        "indirect": {
        }
    },
    "test-dependencies": {
        "direct": {},
        "indirect": {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you are trying to use is outdated. `Date` was removed from `core` in Elm 0.19, with no direct replacement, or indirect replacement that covers the exact same functionality, as far as I'm aware. `elm/time` is intended as the official successor of both `Date` and `Time`, but it offers no date/time string parsing which is what you need here.

The old `Date.fromString` was just a thin wrapper over the JavaScript parsing API, and therefore not very consistent or well-defined. Hence why it was removed. In Elm 0.19 you have to use a third-party package that offers more specific functionality, such as [elm-iso8601-date-strings](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-iso8601-date-strings/latest).

If what you receive are ISO 8601 strings you should be able to replace `parseTime` with:

```
import Iso8601
import Time

parseTime : String -> Time.Posix
parseTime string =
    Iso8601.toTime string
        |> Result.withDefault (Time.millisToPosix 0)
```

If, however, what you receive is not in ISO 8601 format, you need to find another package that parses that specific format.